# Converting a list of strings in two cells to rows by combining them together

Tags: r, split

I have a list that has many rows and it's form is for example like this

```
Peter,Sam,Andrew         a,b,c,d
Anna,Susan,Sandra,Annie  e,f,g
```

and I want to convert it to a list like

```
Peter  a
Peter  b
Peter  c
Peter  d
Sam    a
Sam    b
Sam    c
Sam    d
...
Annie  e
Annie  f
Annie  g
```

How can I do that? I tried a for loop on rows and use `strsplit`  function to separate them and then I wanted to combine each of them together but I was unsuccessful and I had error and I couldn't continue it.

Comment: .... And what have you tried?

Comment: Do you have a `data.frame` or a `list`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `cSplit` from `library(splitstackshape)`

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit(cSplit(df1, 'v1', ',', 'long'), 'v2', ',', 'long')
#        v1 v2
# 1:  Peter  a
# 2:  Peter  b
# 3:  Peter  c
# 4:  Peter  d
# 5:    Sam  a
# 6:    Sam  b
# 7:    Sam  c
# 8:    Sam  d
# 9: Andrew  a
#10: Andrew  b
#11: Andrew  c
#12: Andrew  d
#13:   Anna  e
#14:   Anna  f
#15:   Anna  g
#16:  Susan  e
#17:  Susan  f
#18:  Susan  g
#19: Sandra  e
#20: Sandra  f
#21: Sandra  g
#22:  Annie  e
#23:  Annie  f
#24:  Annie  g
```

#### Update

If we have a string like 'str1', we can get 'df1' using `strsplit` and then do the `cSplit`

```
df1 <- data.frame(lapply(strsplit(str1, '\\s'), 
           matrix, ncol=2,byrow=TRUE))
cSplit(cSplit(df1, 'X1', ',', 'long'), 'X2', ',', 'long')
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(v1 = c("Peter,Sam,Andrew", 
 "Anna,Susan,Sandra,Annie"
), v2 = c("a,b,c,d", "e,f,g")), .Names = c("v1", "v2"), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))

str1 <- 'Anna,Susan,Sandra,Annie e,f,g Peter,Sam,Andrew a,b,c,d Anna,Susan,Sandra,Annie e,f,g '
```

Comment: thanks, but how can I do that if I don't want to use data as a vector ? you know my list has too many rows and I can't make vector like you for each line. @akrun

Comment: I tried this in your code V1=as.vector(read.table("1.txt",header=F,sep="\t"))
V2=as.vector(read.table("2.txt",header=F,sep="\t"))  but it convert them as integers even I tried as.character but it doesne't help me @akrun

Comment: @minoo You should provide some dput of a small dataset.  It is not clear whether you have `vector`, `list` or `data.frame`.  The way in which you converte the data.frame to `vector` is also not correct.

Comment: I have a list like this                                                          'Anna,Susan,Sandra,Annie  e,f,g                                                                            Peter,Sam,Andrew         a,b,c,d
Anna,Susan,Sandra,Annie  e,f,g '                                                                   and in the last command I convert it to two list for using it into your code

Comment: @minoo It is not a `list`.  It s a single string if I understand it;

Comment: It is a list with 1264 rows and two variable that each cell contains words that are collapsed by "," . I couldn't write it clearly here

Comment: @minoo Let me give you an example of a `list` `lst <- list(letters[1:2], letters[1:3])` is a `list` of 2 elements.

Comment: OK, so how can i do that by a list like your example?

Comment: @minoo You showed a string like `str1 <- 'Anna,Susan,Sandra,Annie e,f,g Peter,Sam,Andrew a,b,c,d Anna,Susan,Sandra,Annie e,f,g '`  Is this the data you have? i.e. all in a single line with space as separator between the names and lettesr?

Comment: No , It's a list                                                                                                                       Peter,Sam,Andrew         a,b,c,d
 Anna,Susan,Sandra,Annie  e,f,g

Comment: just like what I wrote in the question

Comment: @minoo I am sorry, your examples are not clear and you are confused about what is a `list/vector` etc..

Comment: @minoo It is better you update the post with the `dput` output of a small example. i.e. `dput(head(yourdata))`